# My JTable is not displaying at all

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I know that a JTable is usually put in a JScrollPane, but I don't want to scroll at all, I want the table to grow when a row is added.
I have used NetBeans IDE 8.2 to create a swing application that almost does what I want with my tables which I've put in JPanels, data and header in separate panels.

I've attempted to go to basics and hand craft the code I need but it isn't displaying the table at all.

```
public NewJFrame1() {
    initComponents();
    JTable table = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    tableModel.addColumn("Type");
    tableModel.addColumn("Folder");
    String[] row = {"Datum1","Datum2"};
    table.setModel(tableModel);
    tableModel.addRow(row);
    this.getContentPane().add(table.getTableHeader());
    this.getContentPane().add(table);
}
```

Comment: A table should be displayed in a JScrollPane so the header and data is displayed properly. Read the JTable API and you will find a link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables` for the basics of using a table.

Comment: ^--- What he said [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
 and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: `initComponents` suggests that you're using Netbeans form editor, you'll probably find that this interferes with your attempts to modify the UI dynamically and you'd be better off not using it (the form editor)

Comment: Yes, but I want to override getPreferredSize and the ScrollPane seems to ignore that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set the model to the table

```
table.setModel(tableModel); //add this to your code
```

Ok, so from what i see ,you are using Netbeans and creating JFrame. If you are inserting your table from the design than there is no need for you to create another table in the constructor.Just simply:

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    tableModel.addColumn("Type");
    tableModel.addColumn("Folder");
    String[] row = {"Datum1","Datum2"};
    tableModel.addRow(row);
    jTable1.setModel(tableModel);// where jTable1 has been created and instantiated automatically by netbeans when you draged and dropt it to your frame , from the design.
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I created a cut down version to demonstrate the problem and missed that out!  It still doesn't display with them connected.

Comment: Thanks @Radu Soigan

Answer (score 0):

Radu Soigan is right, the JTable and TableModel are separate objects which need to be linked together using the setModel(tableModel) method as the table doesn't know where the data to display is at. This is also the same for custom table models, always remember to set it to the JTable after setting up the model.